# Grouping rows on field A or field B

Tags: postgresql

I have data structured as follows:

```
create table T 
( field_1 char(1) not null
, field_2 int not null
,    primary key(field_1, field_2)
);

insert into T (field_1, field_2)
values ('A',1)
      ,('A',2)
      ,('B',3)
      ,('C',3)
      ,('D',4)   
      ,('E',4)
      ,('E',5)
      ,('F',6)
      ,('G',1);
```

I would like to obtain sets that have either field_1 or field_2 in common, like this:

```
field_1     | field_2   | set
-------------------------------
A           | 1         | one
A           | 2         | one
G           | 1         | one
-------------------------------
B           | 3         | two
C           | 3         | two
-------------------------------
D           | 4         | three
E           | 4         | three
E           | 5         | three
-------------------------------
F           | 6         | four
```

Basically, rows having common values in field_1 OR field_2 should be assigned to the same ID. I feel like this is a very basic operation but for some reason I cannot wrap my head around the proper way to do it.

Any clues?

Comment: Interesting question! For future posts, it is better to provide `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for sample data. You will get more attention to your question if it easy to create the scenario.

Comment: What do you do if something can be grouped either way, like say `(A,1),(B,1),(B,2)` Is the `(B,1)` in a group with `(A,1)`, or `(B,2)`. Or, are they all in the same group?

Comment: Thank you @Lennart, duly noted! I usually deal with tables that are already structured so it does not come naturally to me to provide a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @EvanCarroll : In this case, they are all in the same group, as in the case of set 'three' in the example code.

Comment: You're data shows two `D` but the chart shows one, typo?

Comment: @EvanCarroll You're right, it was a typo! Edited.

Comment: What do you do if you have an `(g,1)` does that go with the `a` column at the top, or start a new group?

Comment: @EvanCarroll (G,1) would need to be assigned to the same group as (A,1) and (A,2).

Comment: That's tremendously more problematic then and should be added to your sample data

Comment: @EvanCarroll : Added.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you always using alphanums for field_1, or can we use 1,2,3 for that field too? =)

Comment: @EvanCarroll In the actual database, both fields are integer values and are unique: no integer value in field_1 can be found in field_2 and vice-versa. 

I chose to use letters for field_1 to simplify things.

Comment: I agree, this is a recursion problem at this point.

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: @EvanCarroll 3138 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one attempt that I'm unsatisfied with for several reasons, but it's a start. The idea is to calculate the transitive closure of the graph and then use the minimum field_2 for each field_1 as the group. The latter uses the fact that for two nodes either share the same closure, or the closures are disjoint. As an example:

{(a,1),(a,2),(b,2),(b,3)}

is an impossible transitive closure since if a and b share 2, they must also share 1 and 3:

I used Db2 (which does not support the keyword recursive in CTE as well as ansi join in the CTE)

```
CREATE TABLE t (x char(1) not null, y int not null, primary key (x,y));
INSERT INTO t (x,y)
VALUES ('A',1) 
      ,('A',2)
      ,('B',3)
      ,('C',3)
      ,('D',4)   
      ,('E',4)
      ,('E',5)
      ,('F',6)
      ,('G',1);

with tc (field_1,field_2,n) as (
    select field_1,field_2,0 from t
    union all
    select t1.field_1, t3.field_2,n+1
    from tc as t1, t as t2, t as t3
    where t1.field_2 = t2.field_2
      and t1.field_1 < t2.field_1
      and t2.field_1 = t3.field_1
      and t2.field_2 < t3.field_2
      and t1.field_2 < t2.field_2
      and n <= (select count(1) from t)
), min_closure(field_1,field_2) as (
    -- remove duplicates
    select distinct field_1,field_2 from tc
)
select t.field_1, t.field_2
     , ( select min(field_2)
         from min_closure mc1
         where t.field_1 = mc1.field_1 ) as grp
from t
order by grp;

A           1           1
G           1           1
A           2           1
B           3           3
C           3           3
D           4           4
E           4           4
E           5           4
F           6           6
```

The group can be further adjusted, but I'll leave it like that.

Major problem is that the CTE only sees the previous iteration, so it is very likely that we will add a lot of redundant edges to the tc. For a large graph that won't be very pleasant.

**Edit: attempt to minimize impact by only looking in one direction in graph**

Example of a longer chain:

```
delete from t;
insert into t (x,y) values ('F',5),('F',6),('G',6),('G',7),('H',7),('H',8);
with tc (x,y,n) as (select x,y,0 ...)
select distinct t.x, t.y, min(mc1.y) over (partition by mc1.x) as grp 
from min_closure mc1 join t 
    on t.x = mc1.x order by 3;

F           5           5
F           6           5
G           6           5
G           7           5
H           7           5
H           8           5
```

**EDIT: adjusted for PostgreSQL dialect:**

```
with recursive tc (field_1,field_2,n) as (
    select field_1,field_2,0 from t
    union all 
    select t1.field_1, t3.field_2,n+1
    from tc as t1
    join t as t2
        on t1.field_2 = t2.field_2
     and t1.field_1 < t2.field_1 
    join t as t3
        on t2.field_1 = t3.field_1
       and t2.field_2 < t3.field_2 
    where t1.field_2 < t2.field_2 
      and n <= (select count(1) from t)
), min_closure(field_1,field_2) as (
    -- remove duplicates
    select distinct field_1,field_2 from tc
) 
select t.field_1, t.field_2
     , ( select min(field_2) 
         from min_closure mc1
         where t.field_1 = mc1.field_1 ) as grp
from t 
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and report back. 

In the meantime I outputted my data to R to calculate a pairwise Hamming distance and applied an agglomerative clustering algorithm (single link) to obtain clusters. It worked, but it takes long.

Comment: Is it possible to upload the data-set somewhere? The solution above will probably be very expensive for large graphs, if there is a relevant data-set I can see if I can optimize it.

Comment: @gablee, I have updated the query in an attempt to make generation of tc more efficient